# Brownian motion from two gaussian noise processes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions, brownian-motion, stochastic-processes

Consider some brownian motion for which we obtained the following
solution for the langevin equations

$$
u\left(t\right)=e^{-\alpha t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{\alpha s}\left(\xi\left(s\right)-\xi'\left(s\right)\right)ds
$$

Here, $\xi\left(t\right)$ and $\xi'\left(t\right)$ are two independent
gaussian white noises with zero mean.

**Question:**

1. I believe we can compute $\left\langle u\left(t_{1}\right)u\left(t_{2}\right)\right\rangle $ with the usual procedure where we consider $\left\langle \xi\left(t_{1}\right)\xi\left(t_{2}\right)\right\rangle =g\delta\left(t_{2}-t_{1}\right)$
   if we consider $\left\langle \xi\left(t_{1}\right)\xi'\left(t_{2}\right)\right\rangle =0$
   with the argument that the noise processes are independent; can you
   confirm if I am correct?
2. The book I'm reading shows without proving
   a solution for $\left\langle u\left(t\right)\xi\left(t\right)\right\rangle $
   and I am trying to understand how this is computed. I don't understand
   how the $\xi\left(t\right)$ could go inside the integral of $u\left(t\right)$
   for one to be able to use the usal identity that yields the dirac
   delta. Do you have an idea how this is done? Could you please advise?

Comment: Hello! I am excited to see that you're posting questions and stochastic processes. I am writing to invite you to join me in writing solutions to textbooks in stochastic processes. So far there are two projects, one for the book by Lemons ([link](https://github.com/DanielSank/theory/tree/master/RandomProcesses/Lemons)), and one for the book by Van-Kampen ([link](https://github.com/danielsank/vankampen-stochastic)).

Comment: *"The book I'm reading shows without proving..."* What does the book show? The sentence seems incomplete.

Comment: Also, I am puzzled by the first equation. It looks like a Laplace transform but it's not clear where it came from or what is the meaning of $u(t)$. Adding some more information might help clarify and invite good answers.

Comment: Hi @DanielSank! I tried to reduce my question (and the equation) to focus on the part I don't understand which is dealing with two noise processes and computing that expectation. The book is [this](https://www.amazon.com/Stochastic-Energetics-Lecture-Notes-Physics/dp/3642054102), section 4.2.1.2, pag.153. I'm trying to show equation 4.45 from 4.42, using the solution I obtained for 4.43, not shown in there.

Comment: That looks like a neat book. Any chance you could write your solutions in a way that others can contribute to?

Comment: Maybe later @DanielSank. I'm in a hurry now... Let me come back to you later

Comment: To the second question: First you multiply $u(t)$ with $\xi(t)$. Because the latter is independent of $s$ you can pull it inside the integral. If you now take the expectation value and multiply things out, you end up with a $\langle \xi(s) \xi(t) \rangle$ and a $\langle \xi'(s) \xi(t) \rangle$ term. The latter is zero, and the former is $g \delta(s-t)$. Because the integration goes only up to $s=t$ (rather than extending across $t$ on both sides), a physicist might argue that you only get $g/2$ from the integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the original SDE is probably (see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/190003/46304) for derivation)
$$
\mathrm{d}u_t = \alpha u_t \mathrm{d}t + \mathrm{d}W_t + \mathrm{d}W'_t
$$
from which indeed
$$
u_t = e^{\alpha t} \left(\int_0^te^{-\alpha s}\mathrm{d}W_s + \int_0^te^{-\alpha s}\mathrm{d}W'_s\right) = \mathcal{N}\left(0, \frac{1}{\alpha}(e^{2\alpha t} - 1)\right)
$$
given the two motions are uncorrelated (the correlated case should also be rather simple by the standard mapping to an uncorrelated pair, i.e. $\mathrm{d}W' = \rho \mathrm{d}W + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} \mathrm{d}Z$, where $\mathrm{d}Z$ is a Brownian motion uncorrelated with $\mathrm{d}W$, $\mathrm{d}W'$, and the rest of the math is the same as above).

And we could verify this easily enough with a bit of ugly Python (see Appendix), plotting the PDFs of analytical vs numerical solutions:
[image: PDF of analytical vs (Euler) numerical sol'n to the SDE]

So if I interpret your question correctly, you're asking for the Ito integral

$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\int_0^tu_\tau\mathrm{d}W_\tau\right) 
= \mathbb{E}\left(\int_0^te^{\alpha \tau} \left(\int_0^\tau e^{-\alpha s}\mathrm{d}W_s + \int_0^\tau e^{-\alpha s}\mathrm{d}W'_s\right)\mathrm{d}W_\tau\right)
= \mathbb{E}\left(\int_0^te^{\alpha \tau} \left(\int_0^\tau e^{-\alpha s}\mathrm{d}W_s\right)\mathrm{d}W_\tau\right) 
= \mathbb{E}\left(\int_0^te^{\alpha \tau} e^{-\alpha \tau}\mathrm{d}\tau\right) 
= t
$$

Similarly for variance (though that's not what you asked for), $\mathrm{Var}\left(\int_0^tu_\tau\mathrm{d}W_\tau\right) = \frac{1}{2\alpha^2}(e^{2\alpha t} -1) - \frac{t}{\alpha}$

### Appendix

Analytical vs numerical PDF of the original SDE:

```
import numpy as np
from   scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

alpha = -75.
dt = .001
sdt = np.sqrt(dt)
N  = int(.25/dt)
M  = 10000

ud = np.zeros(M)
for m in range(M):
    u = 0
    w1 = np.random.randn(N)*sdt
    w2 = np.random.randn(N)*sdt
    for n in range(N):
        u += alpha*u*dt + w1[n] + w2[n]
    ud[m] = u

yy, xx = np.histogram(ud, bins=64, density=True)
xx = .5*(xx[:-1] + xx[1:])
plt.plot(xx, norm.pdf(xx, 0, np.sqrt(1./alpha*(np.exp(2*alpha*N*dt) - 1))), xx, yy)
```